# How do I send MMS in Android KitKat (4.4)?

Tags: java, android, messaging, mms

Since KitKat launched, I've seen a lot of articles about how to be the "default messaging app" in Android. There's a lot of good information on what Receivers we need, and how to send and receive SMS.

Everything I've read ignores the elephant in the room, which is how do we actually send MMS messages?! Likewise, I can't find anything about sending Group messages (which are also MMS).

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

In this example, I fill in the name and phone number of the recipient(s) and then call an intent:

```
Name = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_NAME));
Phone = contactStudent ? cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_PHONE)) :
                            cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndexOrThrow(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_P_PHONE));

if (Phone.length()>0 && message.length()>0)  {               
       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
       sms.sendTextMessage(Phone, null, message, null, null); 
  }
else
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
       Name + ":Unable to send message. Phone number or message too short.", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an MMS. This part is well documented, but Google does not tell us how to handle MMS like their Messenger app does yet they clearly expect us to be able to handle it as the default messaging app.

Comment: It sure is an MMS. Works just fine and any other phone it gets sent to sees it as just another message

Comment: An MMS can carry data in the payload which enables it to send images and group messages. This is not an MMS.